# How to find the value of a specific key using counter in the given list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, collections, counter

I have the given list and I want to access the number of times I got the value '6' in the list by using Counter from collections:

```
list1=[3,4,6,4,5,6,2,3,6,7,6]
print("the number of time 6 occurred is ")
print(s6) #s6 is the variable to hold the number of time 6 occurred in the list.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter

list1 = [3,4,6,4,5,6,2,3,6,7,6]
s6 = Counter(list1)[6]
print("the number of time 6 occurred is ")
print(s6)
```

Note, however, that you also can simply use `count()` to count the occurrence of an element in a list:

```
s6 = list1.count(6)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
s6 = Counter(list1)[6]
```

First, use the **Counter** function to get the numbers of values that appear in the list. The key would be the element and the value would be the number of times that value appears in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
list1=[3,4,6,4,5,6,2,3,6,7,6]
print("the number of time 6 occurred is ")
s6 = 0
for i in list1:
  if i == 6:
    s6 += 1
print(s6)
```

Comment: OP wants to use the Counter function.